# SSL for subdomains through Amazon Certificate Manager not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have a domain from GoDaddy hosted on AWS as an EC2 instance (CentOS based). Now I have created 2 subdomains for the website and would be requiring to create more subdomains in the future. So I requested a new Public Certificate in ACM for domain.xyz, www.domain.xyz and *.domain.xyz. In the ELB, I attached this new Certificate. However, it still says as unsecure connection for the new subdomains created and works fine for domain.xyz and www.domain.xyz. What else is to be done. And also will www. *. domain.xyz will also be covered with such a wildcard Certificate?

Comment: Only request a certificate for the naked domain, domain.xyz, and *.domain.xyz, then attach the new certificate to the ELB.

Comment: @hephalump, Thank you... I did request a new certificate for the naked domain - domain.xyz and *.domain.xyz and attached it to ELB. It still is not working...

Comment: It is solved... The A record for the subdomain has to point to EB and not the IP Address of the EC2 instance. and the other thing is I had to handle redirects from http to https. Its working now :)